# Putting timeouts on Prepared statements

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to use prepared statements which operate on a database located quite far away, there is considerable lag and unreliability involved in the network connection used to access this database.
Downtimes of up to a minute are common. 
The problem is that in case of such a failure, if my program tries to execute any prepared statement, the whole thread goes into infinite wait. It never times out and just remains stuck, waiting for a response from the database.

I tried using the method **setQueryTimeout()** to explicitly put a timeout on the execution, but, seems there is some problem with this method wherein it cant work properly if the network fails.

Is there any alternative way around this ?

Comment: Are there any alternative ways to get around this problem , also , i am not really inclined to use a transaction Manager , because it seems to be overkill for a simple timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my knowledge, there is no such alternative if the network itself fails.

The exact details of setQueryTimeout involve the JDBC driver being instructed to send an Out Of Band signal (atleast in the case of the Oracle JDBC driver) to the database to halt the execution of the Prepared Statement; this part is important, as it depends on the support built into the driver and the database. Following this, it is upto the database to schedule execution of this 'cancel' operation; this could take a while if things have to be rolled back or if other transactions have to be executed etc.

Given the first part of the nature of the implementation, it is quite unlikely that a "clean" implementation of a timeout feature can be established. You might want to investigate the use of a transaction manager here (JTA perhaps), but I'm not sure if will encounter another set of bizarre exceptions (think heuristic exceptions).

**Addendum**

Using a thread monitor that monitors the execution of other threads and kills the 'stuck' threads might be a bad idea. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469092/how-independent-are-threads-inside-the-same-process) would help answer why such an activity should be avoided. This is also the [tactic chosen by WebLogic Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709410/weblogic-stuck-thread-protection/2711266#2711266).

Comment: Are there any alternative ways to get around this problem , also , i am not really inclined to use a transaction Manager , because it seems to be overkill for a simple timeout.

Comment: If your database allows for it, establish a cap on the amount of time that a query can execute. The Oracle DB allows for this via the use of resource plans that specify the value of the MAX_EST_EXEC_TIME - queries that exceed the limit specified as the MAX_EST_EXEC_TIME value. will result in the Oracle session being killed.